# How to pass a C++ function pointer as argument with some fixed values?

Tags: c++, syntax, arguments, function-pointers

I would like to use function pointers in a specific case. I am using a function `foo` with the following prototype

```cpp
foo(double (*func)(double,double));
```

I can call `foo`the normal way :

```cpp
double bar(double x, double y) {
    //stuff
};

int main(void) {
    foo(bar);
    return 0; 
};
```

but I would like to freeze the value of `x` in order to get a function equivalent to `double (*func)(double)` like this :

```cpp
foo(bar(x,double))
```

Does a syntax similar to this exists in C++ ?

Comment: Check out `std::bind`. You can bind a value to one or more arguments in a function.

Comment: If you don't have C++11 support for `std::function` and `std::bind` with placeholders found in `<functional>` then you can use the Boost equivalents.

Answer (score 2):

Here's two alternatives if you don't wanna use `std::bind`/`std::function`.

Assuming your compiler supports converting stateless lambdas to function pointers you could use a lambda to bind `x`:

```
void foo(double (*f)(double, double)) { (*f)(3.14159, 2.71828); }

double bar(double x, double y) { return x * y; };

int main()
{
    foo([](double x, double y) -> double { return bar(1.0, y); });
    return 0;
}
```

Or you could even change `foo` into a template that accepts arbitrary function objects. That way you can use lambdas that have captures:

```
template<typename TFunc>
void foo(TFunc f) { f(3.14159, 2.71828); }

double bar(double x, double y) { return x * y; };

int main()
{
    double fixedprm = 1.0;
    foo([fixedprm](double x, double y) -> double { return bar(fixedprm, y); });
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::bind` if you have C++11. Consider this example that transforms a vector by adding 5 to each element in one swift movement:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;

#include <functional>
using std::plus;
using std::bind;
using std::placeholders::_1;

#include <vector>
using std::vector;

#include <algorithm>
using std::transform;

int main()
{
    vector<int> v {1, 3, 6};

    //here we bind the value 5 to the first argument of std::plus<int>()
    transform (v.begin(), v.end(), v.begin(), bind (plus<int>(), _1, 5));

    for (int i : v)
        cout << i << ' '; //outputs "6 8 11"
}
```

---

As for your example, I was able to write something close to it like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;

#include <functional>
using std::bind;
using std::function;
using std::placeholders::_1;

void foo (function<double (double, double)> func) //take function object
{
    //try to multiply by 3, but will do 2 instead
    for (double i = 1.1; i < 5.6; i += 1.1)
        cout << func (i, 3) << ' '; 
}

double bar (double x, double y)
{
    return x * y;
}

int main()
{
    foo (bind (bar, _1, 2));
}
```

Output:

```
2.2 4.4 6.6 8.8 11
```

I might have overcomplicated something though. It was actually my first time using both `std::bind` and `std::function`.